# Facebook Omniauth: This authorization code has expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, neo4j, facebook-oauth, neo4j.rb

I first got this error on a callback for my facebook login in rails. I can't remember the rest of it but after that, I can't reproduce it.

I am now getting an error when I do the same login attempt

`if user = User.find_from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])`

which puts the error on

`User.where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).limit(1).first`

It simply says
`Node with id 133354` and `Neo4j::Session::CypherError in SessionsController#create`

Here's some code on the client side authorization which is based off the http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"] %>', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse
    , scope: "public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_friends"


  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true

  if $('#sign_out').length > 0
    Fb.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      window.location = $('#sign_out').attr("href") if !response.authResponse
```

Not entirely sure where to start to debug this?

Update:
It seems I can't even acesss `http://localhost:7474/browser/` When I try to pull up all nodes, it gives me "unknown error". First error has wrecked havoc on the db??

Comment: What's the full body of the cypher error?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by full body of the cypher error. In my browser, I only get "unknown error" when I click `.` to try to get all. If I click a specific node label like event, I get `Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound` When I hit the login on my web app, I get the `Node with id 133354` part. Doesn't seem to be anything else

Comment: Clear your cookies or session data then try logging in again. It's looking for a node that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: this shouldn't effect my `http://localhost:7474/browser/` though. This has happened before actually. But I needed to reset my db anyways last time, so I didn't worry about it then.

Comment: Gonna put in a db reset in a bit unless you have any other insight :( Need to also figure out what caused the first error cause this can't happen on production!

Comment: Perhaps you can share your path/to/neo/data/graph.db/messages.log ?